# Dividing a list of strings

Tags: c#, string, list

Didn't quite know what to title this question so please feel free to edit.

I have a list of strings where all elements are strings with a length of 40.
What I want to do is split the list elements at character 20 and push the last part of the now divided string to the next element in the list, appending all other elements in the list.

E.g.

```
list[0] = 0011
list[1] = 2233
list[2] = 4455
            ^split here
// new list results in:
list[0] = 00
list[1] = 11
list[3] = 22
list[4] = 33
list[5] = 44
list[6] = 55
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do they all begin with `00`? If so, you could just replace that from each string. If not, are they all guaranteed to be exactly 4 characters long?

Comment: What is the pattern for splitting?

Comment: @downvoter, care to explain? I would really like to learn how to improve my questions, but this gives me nothing...

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev What do you mean? I want to split it in half.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen I've downvoted (and voted to close) because you haven't shown us what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Stijn, thanks for the explanation. That being said, I have tried to figure out how to try, but I don't even come that far. If I were to show you what I have tried I it would be blank, cause I had absolutely no idea.

Comment: @Wilhelmsen Try to go over the process of how you would do this without a computer. You have sheet of paper with a list of strings, you'd go over the list items one by one, you'd take the first half of the item and add it to a new sheet of paper, then you'd take the second half of the item and add it to the new sheet of paper. Hmm, that sounds like a [`foreach` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx) with [`Substring()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx)

Comment: @Stijn I'll take note of that, thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
list = list.SelectMany(s => new [] { s.Substring(0, 20), s.Substring(20, 20) })
           .ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = list.SelectMany(x=>new[]{x.Substring(0, 20), x.Substring(20)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want to do that, but it's quite simple with linq:

```
List<string> split = list.SelectMany(s => new []{s.Substring(0, 2), s.Substring(2)}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must work with the existing array:

```
        const int elementCount = 3;
        const int indexToSplit = 2;

        string[] list = new string[elementCount * 2] { "0011", "0022", "0033", null, null, null };

        for (int i = elementCount; i > 0; --i)
        {
            var str = list[i-1];
            var left = str.Substring( 0, indexToSplit );
            var right = str.Substring( indexToSplit, str.Length - indexToSplit );

            var rightIndex = i * 2 - 1;

            list[rightIndex] = right;
            list[rightIndex - 1] = left;
        }

        foreach( var str in list )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( str );
        }
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "work with the existing array" since all the other answers use it as an input as you have and allocate an additional array, also as you have.

Comment: My input array is also my output array.